# How to call a function in a UserControl (code behind) using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, user-controls

How can I call a function in a UserControl (code behind - UserControl.ascx.cs) using javascript?
The following doesn't seem to work. It only works if I move the function (AddLike) to the code behind of the parent page that nests the UserControl. If the function to be called is in the code behind of the UserControl itself, it doesn't work

UserControl.ascx

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "UserControl.ascx.cs/AddLike", //This doesn't seem to work
    data: "{ IDphoto :" + IDphoto + "}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
})
```

UserControl.ascx.cs

```
[WebMethod]
public static string AddLike(int IDphoto)
{
        //My code        
}
```

parentPage.aspx

```
<uc:UserControl runat="server" />
```

Comment: Try removing the '.cs' from the url. It should probably be just "UserComtrol.ascx/AddLike"

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call `WebMethods` from usercontrol. Put this `WebMethod` in code behind of page in which your control will be loaded. Change it like this

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "parentPage.aspx/AddLike", 
data: "{ IDphoto :" + IDphoto + "}",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
})
```

Comment: The purpose of UserControls is that they are re-usable. If I have 10 pages that will nest the UserControl does it mean that I have to write the WebMethods 10 times? That sounds "Not right". Ironically your solution is the only one that seems to work..... Vicious circle!

Comment: Actually this is not my solution it is default behaviour of ASP.NET.

Comment: And you can write webmthod in a page and create a function that in JS in which your ajax method will be called. You can reuse that function.

Comment: That's what I did actually.... But I was hoping to find a straight forward solution!Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call a `WebMethod` defined in code behind of user control. So what you can do to avoid repetitive code is define your method as a `static` one in code behind of user control like this:-

```
public static string AddLike(int IDphoto)
{
        //My code        
}
```

And then call this method from your respective `aspx` page, which obviously you will trigger from Javascript:-

```
[WebMethod]
public static string AddLikeMethod(int Id)
{
    return UserControl.AddLike(Id); 
}
```

Finally you can call this method as usual:-

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default.aspx/AddLikeMethod", 
    data: "{ IDphoto :" + IDphoto + "}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
})
```